# Android - DialogFragment With Serializable Callback Crashes on Fragment Destruction

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

My fragment has a dialog fragment and to receive a callback when the dialog's button is clicked, I pass a serializable interface to its arguments.

The problem is, whenever the dialog is displayed if the user switches to the android home screen, the app crashes.

NOTE: According to my logs, destruction order is starting from the main fragment and ending with the dialog fragment.

***Code to init dialog fragment:***

```
       Navigation.findNavController(binding.root).navigate(GameFragmentDirections.actionGameFragmentToPauseDialogFragment(
                object : PauseDialogFragment.ResumeGameListener
                {
                    override fun onResume()
                    {
                        isGamePaused = false
                        onStartGame(_screenSizePairXY)
                    }
                }))
```

***Serializable Callback Interface:***

```
interface ResumeGameListener : Serializable
{
    fun onResume()
}
```

***StackTrace***

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = ui.game.GameFragment$onGameOver$1)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1714)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1662)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:875)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:915)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:125)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1516)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1395)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1380)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:51)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1683)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1589)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:875)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:915)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:127)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1516)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1395)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1380)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:51)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1683)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1589)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:875)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4008)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.developerkurt.ghosky.ui.game.GameFragment
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1709)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1662) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:875) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:915) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:125) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1516) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1395) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1380) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:51) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1683) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:875) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:915) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:127) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1516) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1395) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1380) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:51) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1683) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:875) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233) 
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4008) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Parcelable instead of Serializable has solved the issue. However, I still do get an IllegalArgumentException exception saying: *"current action/destination cannot be found from the current destination*" when navigating.

But it doesn't crash the app or cause any kind of side effects (at least in my app, I'd suggest you run test cases).

Note: Just in case I have wrapped the block in try-catch.

***Code to init dialog fragment:***

```
   try
        {
            Navigation.findNavController(binding.root).navigate(GameFragmentDirections.actionGameFragmentToPauseDialogFragment(
                    object : PauseDialogFragment.ResumeGameListener
                    {
                        override fun onResume()
                        {
                            isGamePaused = false
                            onStartGame(_screenSizePairXY)
                        }

                        override fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel?, p1: Int)
                        {
                        }

                        override fun describeContents(): Int = 0
                    }))

        }
        catch (e: Exception)
        {
            Timber.w(e.fillInStackTrace())
        }
```

***Parcelable Callback Interface:***

```
 interface ResumeGameListener : Parcelable
    {
        fun onResume()
    }
```

Comment: Is it ok to not implement writeToParcel method?
Found out that all the errors were comming from writing this parcelable to destination.
What's the impact?